# Bakeries in Wellcome in Hong Kong

Tags: food-and-drink, hong-kong, shopping

There is a chain of supermarkets called Wellcome in Hong Kong. At least one of them has a bakery inside (the one I'm talking about is near Victoria Park, 25 Great George St, Causeway Bay, Hong Kong). But this is the only Wellcome I've seen in HK that has a bakery. Are there others? If so, is there a list of such stores?

Comment: I can't find any such thing on their web site! Though they are happy to tell you all about getting free parking.

Comment: Maybe this has to do with the fact that the Wellcome near Victoria Park is "Wellcome Supercenter" instead of just "Wellcome"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be related to travel.

Comment: My conjecture from the previous comment is wrong: there are Wellcome Supercenters with no bakeries.